# Debug Watson Assistant webhook

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

My Watson Assistant dialog has a webhook call to an IBM Cloud Functions action. After I change the code in the action function and "Try it out" again in Watson Assistant, it doesn't pick up the change. Is there some cache I need to clear, or something I need to restart each time I make a code change?

Comment: I am not aware of any cache, and have not had any such issues when editing and testing cloud functions/actions with Watson assistant. Although I do my testing via my external Watson Assistant client. May be worth creating a "Preview" Assistant integration, and testing via this built in client. If you log out and back in to the dialog workspace, do you still have the issue. If you add additional return fields, to test, do these appear?

Answer (score 0):

In Watson Assistant in the "Try it out" are links / buttons to clear everything or to manage context variables. There you can reset the "Try it out" bot.

In general, when you assign values to a variable the value is kept [until you clear or delete it](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime#dialog-runtime-context-delete). Thus, if you do not set input variables to null to clear them they are reused without asking the user for input again.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I had commented out some lines in the web action editor where they turned green to indicate a comment. But these commented lines were still being executed, despite saving my changes and pressing "Clear" on "Try it out" many times. I finally deleted the lines and things seem to work normally. Not sure what would have caused this but if it happen again I'll document it.